# Div overlapping another div -Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, overlap

First of all Im very new to web development and bootstrap.

Im trying the page to be responsive, but when the browser is resized, divs are overlapping.

- here is a pic of zoomed out and zoomed in page --- (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Pm4.jpg)

As you can see, **"main-content"** is the top div and the bottom white div is the **"content"**

the top 3 pics (**top-hive**) and bottom 2 pics (**bottom-hive**) are also in a separate div. When zoomed out these pics goes beyond its placement div.

Could some one please explain a way around this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>S.H.I.E.L.D</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="nav container">
    </div>

    <div class="main-content container">
        <div class="top-hive row">
            <img src="images/hive1.png">
            <img src="images/hive2.png">
            <img src="images/hive3.png">
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-hive row">
            <img src="images/hive4.png">
            <img src="images/hive5.png">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content container">

    </div>

    <div class="footer container">
        <h5>Copyright (2015)</h5>
    </div>





    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url(../images/BG_01.png) repeat fixed top center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
/*NAV*/
.nav {
    background: url(../images/header_01.png);
    background-position: center;
    height: 417px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
/*MAIN CONTENT*/
.main-content {
    background: url(../images/CBG_03.png) no-repeat;
    height: 684px;
    background-position: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -215px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.top-hive {
    margin-top: 106px;
}
.top-hive img {
    padding: 5px;
}
.bottom-hive {
    margin-top: -60px;
}
.bottom-hive img {
    padding: 5px;
}

/*CONTENT*/
.content {
    background: url(../images/CBG2_03.png) no-repeat;
    height: 621px;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
.text h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2.1em;
}
.text p {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.footer {
    background: #050719 url(../images/footer_02.png)repeat;
    height: 178px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
}

/*FOOTER*/
.footer h5 {
    color: #58a7d9;
    margin-top: 127px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the hexagons are being pushed down with the smaller browser width, causing the whole thing to be three hexagons high instead of two.

Since you set an explicit height on the `.main-content` it can't grow to contain the new arrangement of the hexes. You could set a `min-height` on the `.main-content` div:

```
.main-content {
    background: url(../images/CBG_03.png) no-repeat;
    min-height: 684px; // min-height
    background-position: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -215px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Likewise, if you need the height to remain the same at all times, you could use a media query for smaller screens and change the size of the hexagons on smaller screens so that they don't wrap to a new line.

*edit: it would also be more helpful if you post the code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen](https://codepen.io) instead of an imgur link so that we can edit and test the code ourselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer ! i am satisfied how it is currently, but is it possible for the background img to fill the height as it goes on. right now it looks like this -----( http://imgur.com/6kY9rkP ) sorry its my first question here, next time ill use jsfiddle. thankyou.

Comment: No problem. You have the background-size set to ```100% auto```, you could set it to ```background-size: 100%;``` so that it covers 100% of the div in both directions but this will stretch the image vertically. I don't know if that matters to you.